# How can I write a method that receives, processes and returns a 2D char array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, return

normally I'm a Java guy and I'm trying to write a method that receives, processes and returns a 2D char array in C++.

I tried this:

```
char[][] updateMatrix(char (&matrix)[3][3])
{
 matrix [1][2] = 'x';

 return matrix
}

int main() 
{
 char matrix[3][3] = {   {1,2,3},
                         {4,5,6},
                         {7,8,9} };

 matrix = updateMatrix(matrix);
}
```

but I'm not sure if it´s the "right" way to hand over this 2D Array and how I can return it to override the current matrix. (casting solutions are also welcome)

Comment: The short answer is you don't. Wrap your 2D array into a class and return an object of that type.

Comment: 2D arrays are an absolute <expletive deleted> to pass around in C++. The usual recommendation is you use a smarter container such as a `std::vector` or `std::array`

Comment: Also consider using Eigen if you intend to use actual linear algebra in your C++ program, both for performance and simplicity: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html

Comment: Side note: If you pass in an array, it will be passed by reference. Since you can directly manipulate the source array, there's not much point to returning it.

Comment: In C++, if you get parameter by reference, you can just modify it, and make function void

Comment: For your array initialization: `3` is an integer (which can be converted to a char, but I don't think that's what you expect).  Perhaps you want`'3'` which is a char.

Comment: Read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax to return a reference to an array is a bit funky in C++. Long story short the signature of your function should look like this:

```cpp
char (&updateMatrix(char (&matrix)[3][3]))[3][3];
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85ad08d2cc1287ce)

The reason why you'll hardly ever see this written in C++ is because when you pass something by reference, you don't need to return it; instead you'd simply modify it in place (it will be an in/out parameter).

**A case where such a thing is useful is when you need to chain operations**, and you prefer the resulting syntax e.g. `inverse(transpose(matrix))`. If you go with returning the (reference to the) array, it's always simpler to create a typedef and remove some of the clutter:

```cpp
using mat3x3 = char[3][3];

mat3x3& updateMatrix(mat3x3& matrix)
{
    matrix [1][2] = 'x';

    return matrix;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1af8c0a7a687a71)

Comment: Many thanks for your fast answer now it´s simply logical, you helped me a lot.

Comment: @cr_nasty No worries, declarations in C++ can become difficult to understand. I like this utility a lot https://cdecl.org/ which translates from C to english or vice versa